# Why does my Webpack-cleanup-plugin delete my Exclude files?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

**Background**: a simple one page react app + redux + express (in order to upload to heroku).
I already have index.html and images folder in the public folder. I want to run webpack to generate the styles.css and bundle.js that I used in my index.html. I want to use webpack-clean-up-plugin to remove the extra previous files every time I run build, but I don't want that to affect things like index.html and images folder.
According to the documentation:
*Options
If you want to keep some files in the output path, e.g. a stats.json file generated from some other plugins, use the exclude Array option. It accepts globbing as in minimatch.

// Do not delete `stats.json`, `important.json`, and everything in `folder`

```
new WebpackCleanupPlugin({
  exclude: ["stats.json", "important.js", "folder/**/*"],
})
```

**Goal**: to run webpack.prod.js so in the end the public folder has

- index.html
- bundle.js
- bundle.js.map
- styles.css
- style.css.map
- images(folder)

**Webpack.config.prod.js**:

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')  
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }, 
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ 
            filename: "styles.css", 
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"}),
         new CleanWebpackPlugin({
         exclude: ["index.html", "images/*"],
        })
      ],
```

**Current result:**
every time I npm run

```
"build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --mode production",
```

I would get my index.html and images folder deleted. So where did I write wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyways, after reading more I decided not to use this plugin any more. Because people have been repeating similar issues as I have. And the author said on Mar 22 2018 that he doesn't have time to maintain any more that we should dismiss this plugin. 
[view this on github](https://github.com/gpbl/webpack-cleanup-plugin/issues/42)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using exlude
use this option

```
cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ["**/*", "!stats.json","!important.js", "!folder/**/*"]
```

this works for me :) .
Example:

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin({
    root: process.cwd(),
    verbose: true,
    dry: false,
    cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ["**/*", "!stats.json","!important.js", "!folder/**/*"],
})
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation to this? What does it do actually?

Comment: i am not good at explaining this but... it's similar to !true=fales, likewise what  ! mark  doing is telling the plugin to exclude these files

Comment: Attention! The order of the array elements is IMPORTANT!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a path problem.you sould solve it with '__dirname'

Comment: Do you have an example for people having no clue what the actual problem is?

Comment: where do you mean the __dirname? in the exclude? I tried: exclude: [path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'), "__dirname/public/images/*"], but it doesn't work either. I think according to their documentation, it should be just the name of the file or folder within the output folder.

Comment: set the root options with '__dirname'

Answer (score 1):

You can use [remove-files-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Amaimersion/remove-files-webpack-plugin).

Configuration:

```js
plugins: [
  new RemovePlugin({
    before: {
      // expects what your output folder is `dist`.
      test: [
        {
          folder: './dist',
          method: () => true
        }
      ],
      exclude: [
        './dist/index.html',
        './dist/images'
      ]
    }
  })
]
```

Note: i'm the creator of this plugin.

Comment: Thanks. Next time when I need that I will refer to this.

Comment: Hi, how can I remove all *.js files from the dist folder, like with wildcard *.js? I need to skip all folders in /dist and all other files, and remove only *.js files.

Comment: @Vlado Please see "Examples" section - https://github.com/Amaimersion/remove-files-webpack-plugin#examples

Comment: `    new RemovePlugin({
      before: {
        root: './public',
        include: [
          '*',
        ],

        /**
         * Запрещаем удаление важных файлов
         */
        exclude: NOT_DELETE_FILES,
        trash: true,
      },
      watch: {
        root: './public',
        include: [
          '*',
        ],
        exclude: NOT_DELETE_FILES,
        trash: true,
      },
      after: {
        root: './public',
        include: [
          '*',
        ],
        exclude: NOT_DELETE_FILES,
        trash: true,
      }
    })`  why dosn't work?

Comment: @doox911 `include: ['']` - you don't include anything

Answer (score 0):

Apparently files not referenced explicitly are treated as stale and removed. This worked for me to skip cleaning files copied by `CopyWebpackPlugin`

```js
new CleanWebpackPlugin({
   cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false,
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `webpack.CleanPlugin` worked for me (use the `keep` property to exclude files):

```js
const { CleanPlugin } = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins = [
    ...
    new CleanPlugin({
      keep: (filename) => {
        switch (filename) {
          case "images":
          case "index.html":
            return true;      // true: keep the file, don't delete it
          default:            // delete everything else
            return false;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

`keep` accepts a *string*, *regex* or *a function that returns either true or false*.

Make sure to use `dry: true` for testing.

**Note**: This is a built-in plugin, so you don't need to install anything. I couldn't find any documentation for the plugin, but it's somewhere in Webpack's [source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/lib/CleanPlugin.js), probably not all plugins are documented and listed on their [website](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/).